# What are the best practices to think about when sending a username and password to an authentication server?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm wondering what sorts of things I need to keep in mind when sending a username and password to an authentication server using ajax. I'm using phoneGap and jQuery to develop a web app, which I'm very new to, and I want to make sure I go about it the right way. Any advice is welcome.

Comment: My brief comment: use HTTPS

Comment: Don't send the information un-encoded. Use some method to encode before transmission. The best type of encoding would be one-way, so it can't be undone to find the plain-text value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this an app you're building yourself, or will you be talking to an existing web-based service?

Using HTTPS is a must, assuming it's available. If you're building the website yourself, I'd recommend looking into a token-based system, similar to those used by many popular websites.

The basic flow goes like this:

- You, the developer, register with the site for an API key and possibly a token of some kind.
- In your app, you combine the user's password with your app's token and run them through a hashing algorithm.
- Your app submits the hashed password, along with your API key, to the server.
- If the user's credentials check out, the server replies with an authentication token, which is just a short code. Your app has to include this token with every request to the server.
- Authentication tokens may expire at some point, so you may need to reauthenticate at some point.

In general, avoid storing the user's password in plain text. Hash it in a form that's compatible with the server's authentication system, and then store that value.

Comment: I'll be sending the information to an existing web service. Would sending the password hashed over https be enough without using an API key?

Comment: That's going to depend on the web service that you'll be talking to. Do they have any published API documentation? They're probably expecting a certain pattern of interactions. Check out the [flickr API documentation](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/auth.oauth.html) for a detailed example of how these APIs generally work. It's a little more complicated than just "logging in."

Answer (score 2):

You should use a challenge-response mechanism.

The server should send the client a non-reusable expiring nonce and the user's salt.
The client should hash the password with the salt, hash the resulting hash with the nonce, and send that hash back to the server.

The server should store pre-salted password hashes in its database.
It should then hash the stored hash with the nonce, and compare that to the hash from the client.

This makes it impossible for an attacker to learn the original password, even if the attacker is an active man-in-the-middle and has stolen the database.
However, if the attacker steals the database, he will be able to login by bypassing your UI and using the known hash.

Answer (score 0):

I've used Raymond's examples. Also i've hash password in client side.

http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2011/11/10/Example-of-serverbased-login-with-PhoneGap